# Flex Modal SkinnableContainer

Tags: apache-flex, modal-dialog, adobe, flex-spark

I have this SkinnableContainer, what do I need to implement to create modal for this container? For some reasons (mxmlContentFactory, skin) it has to be SkinnableContainer... I cannot use Popup Manager - I position the container with an Spark Move effect (it begins on the edge of the screen and it slides out.

Any ideas, theories, suggestions, please?
Thank you.

EDIT
Here is my code: (mxml)

```
    <s:Application width="800" height="600">
     <RightTabGroup width="100%" height="500" verticalCenter="0">
      <RightTab id="tab1">
       <RightTabHandle id="tab1handle">
        <s:Label />
       </RightTabHandle>
       <RightTabContent id="tab1content">
        <s:TextInput />
        <s:TextInput />
        <s:TextInput />
       </RightTabContent>
      </RightTab>

      <RightTab id="tab2">
       <RightTabHandle id="tab2handle">
        <s:Label />
        <s:Button />
       </RightTabHandle>
       <RightTabContent id="tab2content">
        <s:TextInput />
        <s:Button />
       </RightTabContent>
      </RightTab>

      <RightTab id="tab3">
       <RightTabHandle id="tab3handle">
       </RightTabHandle>
       <RightTabContent id="tab3content">
        <s:TextInput />
        <s:TextInput />
        <s:TextInput />
           etc...
        <s:TextInput />
       </RightTabContent>
      </RightTab>
     </RightTabGroup>

    <s:Button id="Problem 1"/>
    <s:Button id="Problem 2"/>
    <s:Button id="Problem 3"/>
      ...etc
    <s:Group id="Problem N">
    </s:Group>

    </s:Application>
```

RightTabGroup is s:Group with my custom layout
RightTab is s:SkinnableContainer with skin (SkinPart tabContentGroup and tabHandleGroup)
RightTabHandle is s:SkinnableContainer
RightTabContent is s:SkinnableContainer

EDIT2
see this 2 images:
all close - http://tinypic.com/r/11c6ypw/6
one open and active - http://tinypic.com/r/2rgc1uw/6

---

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem.  For some reason **WHAT** has to be a SkinnableContainer?  PopUpManager should work fine with any IFlexDisplayObject; which is implemented by UIComponent, which is a parent of SkinnableContainer.  What does the Spark Move effect have to do with anything?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com See the code & images.  I can always see all the containers.